# Histogram buckets with @Timed aggregated for some default tags

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I'm in the process of enabling histograms for http requests, so I can use histogram_quantile in prometheus.

So I've configured `management.metrics.distribution.percentiles-histogram[http.server.requests]: true` and have also set minimum-expected-value and maximum-expected-value to prevent too many buckets and attempt to reduce the cardinality.

By default spring-boot sets the following WebMvc tags for anything @RestController (exception, method, outcome, status, uri). Which are great and useful (and used) for the http_server_requests_seconds_count metric for example.

However, for the histograms, it creates http_server_requests_seconds_bucket. The size of the list of buckets have been reduced by the minimum/maximum values, but it creates buckets for each unique combination of tags. I don't care too much to have the response time buckets specified for each exception or outcome. For uri/method, yes please.

The documentation says to replace the default tags, to provide a @Bean that implements WebMvcTagsProvider. But I don't want to replace them, because I still want them for the http_server_requests_seconds_count, I just don't need them for the histograms.

Is there anyway to configure it in a way that it aggregates the histogram buckets for particular tags?

Answer (score 1):

On Prometheus side, you should be able to aggregate the metric, you don't need to specify the tags you don't want to drill down to. But if you want them later, you can use them:

e.g.:

`sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{le="30.0"}[5m]))`

vs.

`sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{uri="/smtg", le="30.0"}[5m])) by (status)`

So the tags there to help you if you want more granular data, they won't stop you to see the big picture.

see: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/

If you don't want to have these tags in Prometheus at all, you can use a [`MeterFilter`](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_transforming_metrics) to remove them.

Comment: But the point is I don't want more granular data. Having all that granularity is fine if you have infinite resources, but not so much if you have the SRE team breathing down your neck asking you to reduce your cardinality. Why have metrics of something you won't need.

Comment: @I.Brok I updated my answer, you can use a MeterFilter for this.